# Good examples of open source Google App Engine Django projects

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am looking for a good example of a Django / python based Google App Engine app to use a learning tool.

I have seen some of the other posts and they are mainly Java based and not really what I am looking for.

Any advice?

Thank you in advance,

Kent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaiku and Code Review are two good examples of opensource projects run with GAE/Django.

- http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/
- http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/

Answer (score 1):

i didnt find an open source project but i think i found a good tutorial for you

http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2009/05/28/django-based-blog-on-google-app-engine-tutorial-part-1

i'll keep this post updated when i find more

Comment: I can't give you full checkmark yet, but this is pretty great!  Thank you. If you find anything else please let me know.

Comment: sure thing man , i'll keep the post updated when i stumble upon good articles or projects

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example of the google prediction api in python that uses appengine and Django in order to build a model and use it to predict the results. It is a great application
http://code.google.com/p/google-prediction-api-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/blog_moderation